# String validation with yup without symbols

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup

I am using React.js and the yup library. I want to prevent an input with random symbols, like the ones that are in a binary file. I want to validate a username, that does not have symbols like ¥ or §. This is what I have, do I have to include it in the regex or is there a better way?

```js
username: string().matches(/^[a-z0-9]+$/).required()
```